# how to disable the option "set as background" in the right click dropdown menu in Linux Gnome3

Tags: linux

I like to disable the option "set as background" in the right click dropdown menu of Zorin OS 12.1 core.
Zorin OS 12.1 Core is based on Ubuntu 16.04 and uses the Gnome3

When richt click on a picture you have in the dropdown menu the option to set it as desktop background

I don't want this option available for normal users on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Please run following command and disable the option "set as background".

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Hope your problem is solved soon.

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04 Mate. The default is `false`, but neither setting seems to affect a user's ability to change background, though I did not try rebooting.

Comment: I have run the command like you said but nothing happens.
What should i do after running the command?